# SQL vs Sequelize: Compare json columns using where

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to reproduce this SQL statement:

```
WHERE ("document"."data"#>>'{dtPrevista}' > "document"."data"#>>'{dtConclusao}')
```

unfortunately I cant' figure out how can I do the right part:

```
document"."data"#>>'{dtConclusao}'
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
options.where = {
    "data":
    {
        "dtPrevista":
        {
            $gt: {"dtConclusao"}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result of my attempt:

```
WHERE ("document"."data"#>>'{dtPrevista}') > 'dtConclusao')
```

Also, I've tried the following one

```
options.where = {
    "data":
    {
        "dtPrevista":
        {
            $gt: {"data": {$col: "dtConclusao"}}
        }
    }
}
```

But this one gives me an error on http get (seems that it's not the correct syntax). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately sequelize only supports generating the left side of the where condition from a POJO - you have to write the right side yourself

```
return Document.findAll({
  where: {
    data: {
      dtPrevista:{
        $gt: sequelize.literal(`"document"."data"#>>'{dtConclusao}'`)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, that should work for me ... unfortunately I'm getting trouble with other part of the query ... if you could help me there i would appreciate that ! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071075/use-sequelize-fn-on-both-sides-column-name-and-column-value

Following what you said seems not to be possible doing it, but if there is a workaround I'll be glad.